# A debug assert failed occurred in the program of the MFC Application wizard

Tags: mfc

I used the MFC Application wizard to create a new program, and then an debug assert failed appeared. What is the reason for this and how can I solve it
[image]
I am using Visual Studio 2013 and when I am running, click on `View`-`Toolbars and Docking Windows`-`Customize`-`Toolbars`causes an error.

debug assertion failed winctrl3.cpp line:237

```
230     if (!fDisabled && ((lpDrawItemStruct->itemState & ODS_SELECTED) != 0))
231     {
232         pDC->SetTextColor(GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHTTEXT));
233         pDC->SetBkColor(GetSysColor(COLOR_HIGHLIGHT));
234     }
235
236     if (m_cyText == 0)
237         VERIFY(cyItem >= CalcMinimumItemHeight());
238
239     CString strText;
240     GetText(lpDrawItemStruct->itemID, strText);
```

[image]

I don't know how to search for such information, and I can't understand the error messages.

Comment: That's not an exception. It's a failed debug assertion. The dialog has instructions on what to do next.

Comment: The picture of the wizard you show doesn't match the picture of your program. The project style is "Visual Studio" and the Visual style and colors is probably "Office something". Please [edit] and clarify. Anyway I could not reproduce your problem. OTOH Visual Studio 2013 is really old and the Wizard was full of bugs. You should upgrade to a newer version of Visual Studio. Or maybe the problem is because you chose "chinese" (or whatever asian language) as Resource language.